# How can I draw this figure using Tikz (Damped Oscillations)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, draw, matlab2tikz

[image]

This is a figure realized using `Matlab`, but it gives an awful view to my article when I add it directly, is there any possibility to transform it into a `TikZ` code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Better than pure `tikz` is to use `pgfplots` (which is based on `tikz`).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to draw a figure generated in Matlab within LaTeX would be to export the graph using [matlab2tikz](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz). With this plugin, you can export your figure as a `.tex` file, which you can then input in your manuscript.